# DetailViewController takes forever to load and display

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a "master" `viewController` and a "detail" `viewController`: in the master, when I receive data from a server, I must open the detail viewController (anything is under a `navigationController`).

So, I have a storyboard and the master scene is not "related" to the detail through a segue: the detail has its own Swift class and ID, so the resulting master code, after I receive data, is:

```
let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("detail") as! DetailViewController
(viewController as! DetailViewController).detailItem = dataToPass
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

`detailItem` is a DetailViewController variable, declared this way:

```
var detailItem: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
            print("variable set")
            // configuration code (...)
        }
    }
```

What happens: when I receive data `didSet` fires quite quickly BUT the detail view takes forever to load and open (it opens very quickly if I create a simple button and open it with a segue and without `didSet`).

What am I doing wrong?

Update: this happens even if I remove any code contained in the detail.

I don't know if this can be of any help but when finally the detail opens in the console I read "This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release". I really don't know HOW I'm modifying the autolayout engine

Comment: Did you try a `print` at the end of `didSet()` to see if that's the one (in main thread I guess) that is taking to long? What's the code in `didSet()`? Are you calling WebServices in main thread/synchronously?

Comment: @Larme: I updated the answer: it happens in any case, even if I completely remove didSet and even if I remove any other configuration code. The problem seems to be the code that opens the detail

Comment: And the problem is not the second line (i removed `(viewController as! DetailViewController).detailItem = dataToPass` and the effect is the same)

Comment: You seem to be calling a presentation in a background thread, while all UI modification have to be don in main thread.

Comment: Larme, I don't understand very well what you say: the only thing I can tell you is: 1. I click a button, 2. I get data from a server, 3. when I get data I try to display it in a new screen. I can't believe this can cause errors

Comment: Could you show more code? Where do you do your server call? Where do you try to go to next view controller, etc. For example, as I suppose, you should call `let viewController:UIViewController etc.` here: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {//Call})`

Comment: Ok, I found an SO thread telling the same, what I don't undestand is WHY should the code be wrapped this way (I'll discover it soon, but I was not even aware of this thing). Anyway, I call my code from inside the body of a `session.dataTaskWithRequest`

Comment: Again, you need to show more code. All UI updates in iOS have to be done in main thread. So if you are in a background thread, NOTHING can assume that it will work correctly. That's why you're getting this message in the logs. The dispatch_async/getmainqueue is a way to execute this code in main thread.

Comment: Anyway, by wrapping the code inside `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
 
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  // my code here
 });
});` there's no lag anymore and no errors.

If you want, you can write an answer to the post, I'll mark your answer as the solution that worked

Comment: Larme, problem is there are no explicit threads, so I'm assuming I'm not in the main thread because I'm making an asyncronous request

Comment: Yes, we can guess that's because of the web service call, but again, if you would have shown your code, it would have been simpler and faster.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the sorrounding code wasn't useful